# How to give CultureInfo to TryParse method in F#

Tags: f#

In F#, I am parsing a decimal string with

```
let foo str =
    match Decimal.TryParse str with
    | (true, result) -> Some result
    | (false, _) -> None
```

which uses the current system culture to parse the string. But I actually want to parse the string using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. Can this be done in a pattern matching manner like above? If not, what is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like:

```
 let foo str =
     match System.Decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) with
     | (true, result) -> Some result
     | (false, _) -> None
```

Comment: Thanks Bas. I didn't notice the NumberStyles in the middle, which caused my compile to fail.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use overload that takes `NumberStyles` as the second argument and `CultureInfo` as the third. Since this is a .NET method, the arguments are tupled (except that F# compiler turns the last `byref` argument into a return typle):

```
let foo str =
  match Decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) with
  | (true, result) -> Some result
  | (false, _) -> None
```

The type signature of the method (as shown in Visual Studio tool tip) is:

> Decimal.TryParse(s:string, style:NumberStyles, provider:IFormatProvider, result:byref<decimal>) : bool

When using the method with pattern matching, the compiler turns all `byref` arguments from the end of the argument list into (last) elements of the returned tuple, but it keeps the parameters as a tuple, so you have to call the method using the `TryParse(foo, bar)` notation.

Answer (score 0):

use another overload of [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ew0seb73.aspx) method

```
open System
open System.Globalization
let parse s = 
    match Decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) with
    | true, v -> Some v
    | false, _ -> None
```